# Javascript Mobile Redirecting

Tags: javascript

I am using the JavaScript version of the mobile redirect from:

http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

However I want to avoid infinite redirection loops.

On the mobile version we have a link back to the full desktop version and I don't want
someone to click it and then just redirect back to the mobile main page.

Thoughts/Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra argument to the URL when forcible navigating to the desktop version that prevents the mobile redirect from being written to the page.

Comment: Like a ?=1 or something at the end of the .com portion?

Comment: @Bry4n: I should use something more meaningful, e.g. `?noredirect=true`.

Comment: Yeah I would I was just double checking. Thanks.